# Underscore in Named Arguments

Tags: scala, scala-placeholder-syntax

Can someone explain me what exactly is going on here? I am not fully getting into it right now:

```
val s = Seq(1D,2D,3D,4D)
case class WithUnit(value: Double, unit: String)
s map { WithUnit(_,"cm") } // works
s map { WithUnit(value = _ , unit = "cm") } // error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => value = x$2)
```

I guess the compiler can´t infer the parameter type because I wrote the name of the argument. But why not? It shouldn´t be more difficult only because of stating the name of the argument?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you wrote:

```
 WithUnit(value = _, unit = "cm")
```

You wanted it to mean:

```
 x => WithUnit(value = x, unit = "cm")
```

But if you take a close look at the error message, you'll see that the compiler didn't see it that way, it parsed it as:

```
 WithUnit(x => value = x, unit = "cm"})
```

As you can see, the _ is scoped more tightly than you wanted.

_ always picks the tightest non-degenerate scope it can. The scope is determined purely syntactically, during parsing, without regard to types.

By non-degenerate, I mean that the compiler *didn't* think you meant:

```
WithUnit(value = x => x, unit = "cm")
```

Tightest non-degenerate scope means the scope defined by the innermost function parenthesis relative to the underscore.  Without such a rule the compiler wouldn't be able to know which _ corresponds to which function when function calls are nested.

Comment: Ahh, I see! Now I have a deeper understanding.... _tightest non-degenerate scope_ ... I will remember that! Thank you!

Comment: Arguably, though, this is a bug. `WithUnit(_, "cm")` worked because it was treated as a partially applied function, not as a an anonymous function literal. It doesn't get treated the same way when used with named parameters, which I suspect was just an oversight.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think the distinction you're drawing between "partially applied function" and "anonymous function literal" exists.

Comment: Arguably, this is a bug now that `f(id = e)` can no longer mean assignment. The syntax used to be "assignment or named arg", now it is only "named arg", and the expression is `_`, and the OP's intuitive reading is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
scala> val withUnits = s map { x => WithUnit(value = x, unit = "cm") }
withUnits: Seq[WithUnit] = List(WithUnit(1.0,cm), WithUnit(2.0,cm), WithUnit(3.0,cm), WithUnit(4.0,cm))
```

The problem is the usage of the underscore to directly define an anynymous function.

A detailed description is in [chapter 8.5. Placeholder syntax in the "Programming in Scala" book](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#8.5).

Comment: Thank you for the link, sometimes one forgets about checking the bible ;)