# Underscore in List.filter

Tags: scala

Why this is not working:

```
List(true,false).filter(_).size
```

The error says:

```
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function 
((x$1) => List(true, false).filter(x$1).size)
    List(true,false).filter(_).size
                            ^
```

but the following works (looks just the same for me):

```
List(true,false).filter(a => a).size
```

I'm using Scala 2.9.0.1.

Comment: see also: [tightest non-degenerate scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259006/underscore-in-named-arguments/5259946#5259946)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Handling of `_` is a bit tricky in Scala and as a side note I think error handling should be improved a bit. Back to topic, have a look at this example:

```
def twice(i: Int) = i * 2
def gt2(j: Int) = j > 2

List(1,2,3) filter gt2
```

This compiles fine and works as expected. However trying to compose functions results with cryptic error:

```
List(1,2,3) filter gt2(twice(_))

  error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => twice(x$1))
          List(1,2,3) filter gt2(twice(_))
                                     ^
```

What happened? Basically when Scala compiler sees underscore it *binds it* into the most immediate context, which is `twice(_)` in this case. This means we are now calling `gt2()` with a *function* `twice` as an argument. What compiler knows is that this function takes an argument and returns the same type. Arguably it should figure out the type of this argument and return type is `Int` based on `twice()` signature, however it uses `x$1` placeholder temporarily until he figures that out later.

Unfortunately it is unable to do that since `gt2()` expects an `Int` while we are providing a function (at least that is what the compiler thinks).

So why does:

```
List(1,2,3) filter {k => gt2(twice(k))}
```

work? The compiler does not know the type of `k` in advance. However it knows that `gt2` returns `Boolean` and expected an `Int`. It also knows that `twice()` expects an `Int` and returns one as well. This way it infers the type of `k`. On the other hand the compiler knows from the beginning that `filter` expects `Int => Boolean`.

---

That being said back to your case. The underscore alone (`(_)`) is not consider a "*context*" so the compiler searches for another most immediate enclosing context. The `!_` would have been considered a function on its own, as well as `_ == true`. But not the underscore alone.

So what is the closest immediate context (I'm sure there is a scientific name for that...) in this case? Well, the whole expression:

```
(x$1) => List(true, false).filter(x$1).size
```

The compiler thinks you are trying to create a function that takes some parameter of unknown type and returns something of the type of an expression: `List(true, false).filter(x$1).size`. Again arguably it should be able to figure out that `filter` takes `Boolean => Boolean` and returns `Int` (`.size`), but apparently it doesn't.

---

So what can you do? You have to give the compiler a hint that the underscore should be interpreted in smaller context. You can say:

```
List(true,false) filter (_ == true)
List(true,false) filter (i => i)
List(true,false) filter identity
```

Comment: Great explanation. I might have to create some fake accounts in order to vote it up a couple of times.

Comment: Considering the many questions to this behaviour, I think it is actually better that the compiler does not figure out that a function `(Boolean => Boolean) => Int` would fit but that it rather fails compiling it.

Answer (score 3):

The first error is because Scala doesn't know what to make of _.   So try this...

```
List(true,false).filter(_:Boolean).size
```

After that, you get more info:

```
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
found   : Boolean
required: (Boolean) => Boolean
 List(true,false).filter(_:Boolean).size
```

It's just evaluating the _ just as the value and not as function.  Per the ScalaDoc

```
filter (pred: (A) ⇒ Boolean): GenTraversable[A]
```

Answer (score 2):

I see the error message is much improved! Let's see what the error message said you wrote, and your working version:

```
((x$1) => List(true, false).filter(x$1).size)
          List(true,false).filter(a => a).size
```

Or, adjusting spaces, parenthesis and variable names:

```
a => List(true, false).filter(a     ).size
     List(true, false).filter(a => a).size
```

Does it look the same now?

Briefly, when you pass underscore in place of a parameter, you are doing [*partial function application*](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#8.6). You are probably more familiar with underscores being used as placeholders for parameters in anonymous functions, which is what happens when it appears in an expression, like `_ + 1`. These two uses are different, even if they both result in an anonymous function.