# Scala placeholder syntax

Tags: scala

There is something that I can't quite understand hope someone can shed some light..
I have Seq[String]

```
val strDeps: Seq[String] = ...
```

and I tried to sort it on the reverse of the using the sortWith method and I get the following error.

```
scala> print(strDeps.sortWith(_.reverse.compareTo(_.reverse) < 0) mkString ("\n"))
<console>:15: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 2
              print(strDeps.sortWith(_.reverse.compareTo(_.reverse) < 0) mkString ("\n"))
                                                                    ^
```

But when I try sort it without doing a reverse it works fine.

```
scala> print(strDeps.sortWith(_.compareTo(_) < 0) mkString ("\n"))
// this is fine
```

Also it works fine without the placeholder syntax

```
scala> print(strDeps.sortWith((a,b) => a.reverse.compareTo(b.reverse) < 0) mkString ("\n"))
// this works fine too
```

Comment: See also: [Underscore in List.filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695270). The same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`_` expands only to the smallest possible scope.

The inner `_.reverse` part is already interpreted as `x => x.reverse` therefore the parameter is missing inside `sortWith`.

Answer (score 8):

```
compareTo(_)
```

Is a partially applied method. It just means "compareTo, but without applying the first parameter". Note that `_` is *not* a parameter. Rather, it indicates the *absence* of a parameter.

```
compareTo(_.reverse)
```

Is a method taking an anonymous function as parameter, the parameter being `_.reverse`. That translates to `x => x.reverse`.