# scala newbie having troubles with tuples and closures

Tags: scala, closures, tuples

I have a List of tuples, and I'd like to traverse and get the value of each element.

this is the code:

```
scala> val myTuples = Seq((1, "name1"), (2, "name2"))
myTuples: Seq[(Int, java.lang.String)] = List((1,name1), (2,name2))

scala> myTuples.map{ println _ }
(1,name1)
(2,name2)
res32: Seq[Unit] = List((), ())
```

So far, so good, but

```
scala> myTuples.map{ println _._1 }
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
    myTuples.map{ println _._1 }
```

I also tried with:

```
scala> myTuples.map{ println(_._1) }
<console>:35: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1._1)
          myTuples.map{ println(_._1) }

scala> myTuples.map{ val (id, name) = _ }
<console>:1: error: unbound placeholder parameter
       myTuples.map{ val (id, name) = _ }

scala> myTuples.map{ x => println x }
<console>:35: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: ?{val x: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method any2Ensuring in object Predef of type [A](x: A)Ensuring[A]
 and method any2ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](x: A)ArrowAssoc[A]
 are possible conversion functions from Unit to ?{val x: ?}
              myTuples.map{ x => println x }
```

Declaring the variable, and using parentheses did the trick, but I'd like to know why the other options didn't work

these worked fine

```
myTuples.map{ x => println("id: %s, name: %s".format(x._1, x._2)) }

scala> myTuples.map{ x => println("id: %s, name: %s".format(x._1, x._2)) }
id: 1, name: name1
id: 2, name: name2
res21: Seq[Unit] = List((), ())

scala> myTuples.map{ x => val(id, name) = x; println("id: %s, name: %s".format(id, name)) }
id: 1, name: name1
id: 2, name: name2
res22: Seq[Unit] = List((), ())

scala> myTuples.map{ x => println(x._1) }
```

What happens to me, with my first steps with scala, is that insisting a little bit you get what you want, but you are unsure why the first options you tried didn't work...

Comment: FWIW, `map` is used when you want to transform the contents of a collection. Since you don't care about the results, `foreach` is the preferred method.

Comment: nice tip, and it also makes much more clearer the intention of the dev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the options that didn't work:

```
scala> myTuples.map{ println _._1 }
```

**Short answer:** In Scala, you always need to use parens around `println`'s argument. **Long answer:** Scala only infers parenthesis for infix methods, meaning code of the forms `object method argument` gets interpreted as `object.method(argument)`. No object is specified, so no parenthesis are inferred. You can see this directly by:

```
scala> println "Boom!"
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
       println "Boom!"
               ^
```

Next, `myTuples.map{ println(_._1) }`. <strike>It's not immediately clear to me why this doesn't work, since this should be equivalent to `myTuples.map{ x => println(x._1) }`, which works.</strike> As [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8260367/115478) show, placeholder/partially applied method syntax applies to the smallest possible scope. So equivalent code would be `myTuples.map { println(x => x._1) }`. Since there's not enough information for scala to infer the type of `x`, you get a 'missing parameter type' error.

Regarding `myTuples.map{ val (id, name) = _ }`, placeholders are used in anonymous functions , whereas here you are initializing `val`'s.

Then for `myTuples.map{ x => println x }`, you're also missing parens.

<strike>Finally, the option that worked for you `myTuples.map{ x => println("id: %s, name: %s".format(id, name)) }`, didn't actually work (look at the data it printed out). My guess if you had already defined `id` and `name` in the REPL, and those are the values being printed.</strike> Your working solutions work fine now.

My solution for doing what you're trying to do would be:

```
myTuples foreach {
  case (id, name) => printf("id: %s, name: %s\n", id, name)
}
```

or

```
myTuples foreach {
  x => printf("id: %s, name: %s\n", x._1, x._2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, excellent answer, and you are right, the solution I gave didn't work, this does:
myTuples.map{ x => println("id: %s, name: %s".format(x._1, x._2)) }
and also this:

myTuples.map{ x => val(id, name) = x; println("id: %s, name: %s".format(id, name)) }

Comment: `myTuples.map{ println(_._1) }` is equivalent to `myTuples.map{ println(x => x._1) }`. Why would it be anything else?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral "Why would it be anything else?" Apparently because I misunderstood the rules about how _ works. Answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want something like:

```
myTuples map { case(id, name) => println(id+": "+name) }
```