# Scala map with partial function as value

Tags: scala

In [Twitter's Scala school](http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/) [collections section](http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/collections.html), they show a Map with a partial function as a value:

```
// timesTwo() was defined earlier.
def timesTwo(i: Int): Int = i * 2
Map("timesTwo" -> timesTwo(_))
```

If I try to compile this with Scala 2.9.1 and [sbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt) I get the following:

```
[error] ... missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => "timesTwo".$minus$greater(timesTwo(x$1)))
[error]     Map("timesTwo" -> timesTwo(_))
[error]                                ^
[error] one error found
```

If I add the parameter type:

```
Map("timesTwo" -> timesTwo(_: Int))
```

I then get the following compiler error:

```
[error] ... type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int => (java.lang.String, Int)
[error]  required: (?, ?)
[error]     Map("timesTwo" -> timesTwo(_: Int))
[error]                    ^
[error] one error found
```

I'm stumped. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It thinks you want to do this:

```
 Map((x: Int) => "timesTwo".->timesTwo(x))
```

When you want this:

```
 Map("timesTwo" -> { (x: Int) => timesTwo(x) })
```

So this works:

```
 Map( ("timesTwo", timesTwo(_)) )
 Map("timesTwo" -> { timesTwo(_) })
```

Note this is not an usual error, see

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7695459/257449.
- [Scala underscore - ERROR: missing parameter type for expanded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627117/scala-underscore-error-missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function)

(and probably more)

Comment: Or `Map("timesTwo" -> (timesTwo _))`

Comment: or `Map[String, Int => Int]("timesTwo" -> timesTwo)`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing telling `scalac` that you want to *lift* the **method** `timesTwo` into a *function*. This can be done with an underscore as follows

```
scala> Map("timesTwo" -> timesTwo _)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int => Int] = Map(timesTwo -> <function1>)
```