# Scala : why can't I filter my Int List properly with placeholder ? e.g : myList.filter(_:Int => _ % 5 == 0)

Tags: scala, type-inference, placeholder, scala-collections

I have a little issue related to placeholder syntax in Scala.
So I have a simple List of numbers :

```
myList = List(13, 24, 10, 35)
```

first, I tried to filter this list like this

```
myList.filter(_ => (_ % 5) == 0)
```

and the compiler complains since it can not infer the parameter type :

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.$percent(5))
```

okay, no problem : I added a type for the parameter

```
myList.filter(_:Int => _ % 5 == 0)
```

now the compiler gives me this :

```
identifier expected but integer literal found.
       someNumbers.filter(_:Int => _ % 5 == 0)
                                       ^
```

do you guys know why I have this weird error ? I really don't get it ...

thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Underscore in List.filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695270/underscore-in-list-filter)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have no idea, but this:

```
identifier expected but integer literal found.
       someNumbers.filter(_:Int => _ % 5 == 0)
                                       ^
```

is an awesome error! Well, not in the sense people would like it, but you managed to almost write something syntactically correct and utterly different from what you intended. First, let's look at rewriting that is valid code:

```
someNumbers.map(_: Int => _ <:< Any)
```

Now, you see that there are only two differences from it to what you wrote (up to the error position): `%` replaced with `<:`, and `5` replaced with `Any` (as the compiler wanted -- an identifier instead of a number).

You can compile and run the code above, and it will return something, so let's try to break it down. First, consider the two statements below:

```
someNumbers.map(_ + 1)
someNumber.map(_) // does not compile
```

They each mean something slightly different, and can be rewritten like this:

```
someNumbers.map(x => x + 1)
x => someNumbers.map(x)
```

The first one compiles because, at the time the `x` parameter is declared, the compiler knows what type is expected. The second one does not compile because, at the time the compiler sees `x`, it has no idea how it is going to be used. Granted that's only because the compiler has rewritten the code, but that's how it goes.

The important thing here is that, when you added `: Int`, the compiler started trying to compile what you wrote the second way.

The thing you intended to write is not valid code. For example:

```
someNumbers.map(x => x + 1) // valid code
someNumbers.map((x: Int) => x + 1) // valid code
someNumbers.map(x : Int => x + 1) // "invalid" code
```

To be more precise, the third example is "invalid" because the compiler doesn't know *where* the type ends! To understand why, look at this statement:

```
val f: Int => Int = x => x
```

Here we have `=>` appearing twice, but each time with a different meaning! The first case, `Int => Int`, is syntactic sugar for `Function1[Int, Int]`. In other words, `=>` in `Int => Int` is part of the type.

In the second case, `x => x` (roughly) stands for `new Function1[Int,Int] { def apply(x: Int) = x }`. The `=>` in this code indicates the presence of an anonymous function, and separates its parameter from its body.

Now we can understand how the compiler interpreted `someNumbers.filter(_: Int => _ % 5 == 0)`. Like this:

```
someNumbers.filter(_: Int => _ % 5 == 0) // gets rewritten as
(x: Int => _ % 5 == 0) => someNumbers.filter(x)
```

Meaning that `Int => _ % 5 == 0` was assumed to be the type. We already saw why `=>` doesn't stop it, but the error only happened on `5`! What's going on between here and there?

First, I'll get back to my compilable example. It makes use of a Scala construct that isn't very well understood, and not often seen either: the infix *type* notation. That example can be rewritten like below:

```
someNumbers.map(_: Int => _ <:< Any)
someNumbers.map(_: Int => <:<[_, Any])
```

In other words, just like `2 * 2` stands for `2.*(2)`, `Int Map String` stands for `Map[Int, String]`. So that explains why the compiler did not stop at `%` -- it thought it stood for a type -- but it still leaves us with `_`.

At this point, however, the meaning of `_`, particularly in the rewritten form, shouldn't look mysterious: it is an existential type! More specifically, it is the wildcard existential type. The whole thing can be rewritten like this:

```
(x: Function1[Int,<:<[t, Any] forSome { type t }]) => someNumbers.map(x)
```

Or, without any syntactic sugar (but being slightly different in implementation*):

```
new Function1[Function1[Int, <:<[t, Any] forSome { type t }], List[<:<[q, Any] forSome { type q }]] { 
  def apply(x) = someNumbers.map(x) 
}
```

Now, don't you agree this could hardly be farther from what you wanted to write? :-)

(*) Actually, I think `t` and `q` are the same in the original, but I haven't figured any way to write it out without syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Daniel-C-Sobral That was an amazing explanation :-) ... I must admit I was far from being able to explain it that way. Anyway thanks a lot, I think it helped a lot of people have a better understanding of this issue.

Comment: Who ever said Scala was complex?? Maybe things will improve with SIP-18, where existential types and higher kinds are unavailable by default.

Answer (score 6):

You meant this:

```
val myList = List(13, 24, 10, 35)
myList.filter(x => (x % 5) == 0)
```

The placeholder `_` in something like `myList.map(_ + 5)` is shorthand for making a function, in this case `myList.map(x => x + 5)`.  So `myList.map(_ => _ + 5)` because it's sort of saying "map each item in `myList` to the sum of a function `x => x` and 5".

The other use of placeholders in something like this is to ignore the parameter.  So `myList.map(_ => 1)` means "ignore the item and just map everything to 5".  In your case, you need the item to decide whether to filter it, so having `_ =>` doesn't make sense.

The expression `myList.filter(x => (x % 5) == 0)` means "for each `x` in `myList`, keep it if `(x % 5) == 0`".

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. Actually, this solves my problem but I want to understand why the placeholder does not work in this case. Can you please provide me with some explanation ? thanks

Comment: Btw, I will accept your answer in 10 minutes (stackoverflow rules). It's actually the fastest anwser I've ever had on stack so thanks

Comment: @kaffein, I added some explanation.  Does that clear things up?

Comment: thanks a lot for this clear explanation. And following it I did this : myList.filter(_ % 5 == 0) and it rocks :) ... thanks

Comment: Wow, didn't even realize that _ was an acceptable function parameter.  What, does that make 18 different uses for it in the language or 19?

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
myList.filter(_ % 5 == 0)
```