# Why foreach fail with String typed List with toUpperCase?

Tags: scala, foreach

From *Programming in Scala*,we know that `foreach` is a high-order function which takes a procedure with return type `Unit`.So I think the following slice would work:

```
val abcde = List("a","b","c","d","e")
abcde.foreach(print _.toUpperCase)
```

however it tells me that:

```
1: error: ')' expected but '.' found.
  abcde foreach (println _.toUpperCase)
                          ^
```

But these two below both work well:

```
println("abcde".toUpperCase)
abcde.foreach(print _)
```

So what's the difference?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5259946/298389

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two are using `_` in different ways:

```
abcde.foreach(print _.toUpperCase)
abcde.foreach(print _)
```

In the first case, you have an anonymous function where `_` denotes a placeholder for a parameter.

In the second case, `_` means you'd like a function value for the method `print` (an *eta expansion*).

So comparing the two is irrelevant.

More to the point would be this:

```
scala> print "abcde".toUpperCase
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
       print "abcde".toUpperCase
             ^
```

As you can see, this doesn't work, so replacing `"abcde"` with `_` wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `_` in this situation since

```
abcde.foreach(print _.toUpperCase)
```

can't be interpreted as

```
abcde.foreach((print _).toUpperCase)
              ^       ^
```

(since `print` returns `Unit`) and it can't be interpreted as

```
abcde.foreach(print (_.toUpperCase))
                    ^             ^
```

because `print` does not take a function from string to string.

You'll have to do the slightly longer

```
abcde.foreach(s => print(s.toUpperCase))
```

which works fine.

> ***[...] But these two below both work well: [...]***

Both

```
println("abcde".toUpperCase)
```

and

```
abcde.foreach(print _)
```

are perfectly fine and standard ways of writing it. The difference is that `_` can't be used inside an argument as your first attempt illustrates.

Comment: It does not fail because the types are wrong. It already fails during parsing.