# Partially applied functions in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, partial-application

Wondering if you can comment on why following two scenarios behave differently:

The following works:

```
var la= List(12, 13 , 14 ,15);
var func = (x:Int) => println(x)
la.foreach(func)                   // 1
la.foreach(func(_))                // 2
```

But the following does not:

```
var la= List(12, 13 , 14 ,15);
var func1 = (x:Int) => {
    for (i <- 0 to x) yield i*2
 } mkString
la.foreach(println(func1))         // similar to 1 above
la.foreach(println(func1(_)))      // similar to 2 above
```

error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int => ?
la.foreach(println(func1(_)))

Comment: _tightest non-degenerate scope_ : see my comment at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5259946/562716

Answer (score 5):

This case is desugared

```
la.foreach(println(func1(_)))
```

to

```
la.foreach(println(x => func1(x)))
```

So you passing the function to `println`, print return type is Unit and foreach requires some `Int => ?` function.

In contrasting, the first sample in both cases you are feeding `foreach` with `Int => Unit`, while in the 2nd sample in both cases you are feeding `foreach` with `Unit`.

Comment: I understand that by explicitly specify the argument (x) we can make it work.. but why it does not work with partially supplied argument.? In both your code bits, println is still returning Unit.. so how does it  change the behavior for foreach

Comment: It doesn't, it only doesn't type check. See how the desugaring of `func1` is different from `func`

Answer (score 3):

In the second code snippet, you're calling `println` with a function as its argument and then trying to pass the result of that call as an argument to `foreach`. Since `println` does not return a function, but `foreach` wants one, that does not work.

Comment: Thanks! how can we fix this, but still using partially supplied argument?

Comment: @Shalab To the best of my knowledge, you can't. You'll have to use a lambda with explicit arguments.