# Shorter form for boolean predicate

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Underscore in List.filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695270/underscore-in-list-filter)

This works (as intended):

```
List(true, false, true).filter(_ == true).foreach(println)
```

but I can't write it this way:

```
List(true, false, true).filter(_).foreach(println)
```

Why?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518677/partially-applied-functions-in-scala

Answer (score 9):

@sshaef is right, this is a duplicate. The linked answer is *really* verbose though, so here's a  simple answer:

You expect `list.filter(_)` to expand to something like `list.filter(x=>x)`, but instead the Scala compiler treats it the same as `list.filter _`, which is completely different. The result is a partially-applied `filter` on your list instead of filtering your list with the identity function. This is obvious when you try it in the REPL:

```
scala> List(true, false, true).filter(_)
res0: (Boolean => Boolean) => List[Boolean] = <function1>

scala> List(true, false, true).filter _
res1: (Boolean => Boolean) => List[Boolean] = <function1>

scala> List(true, false, true).filter(x=>x)
res2: List[Boolean] = List(true, true)

scala> List(true, false, true).filter(identity)
res3: List[Boolean] = List(true, true)

scala> List(true, false, true).filterNot(!_)
res4: List[Boolean] = List(true, true)
```

Notice how the last case works because we include the `!` operator in front of `_`, so it knows you're using it as an anonymous argument rather than using it to partially apply the function.

Answer (score 2):

Just for another angle, depending on what your goal is, this is just as short and concise:

```
for(a <- List(true, false, true) if a) println(a)
```