# Why "value.foreach(setValue(_.toInt))" can't be compiled

Tags: scala

Scala code:

```
val value = Some("100")
value.foreach( println(_.toInt) )   // !!! can't be compiled
```

The error message is:

> missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1)=>x$1.toInt)

Why it can't be compiled?

PS:
And the following code is valid:

```
value.foreach( _.toInt )
value.foreach( x => println(x.toInt) )
```

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259006/underscore-in-named-arguments/5259946#5259946

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler message is a bit misleading, but it provides you with a hint: it tells you that it interpreted `_.toInt` as `(x$1)=>x$1.toInt`. So, putting it in place, you get

```
value.foreach( println( (x$1)=>x$1.toInt ) )
```

which is obviously not what you intended.

Here's IMO the cleanest way to solve your issue:

```
value.map( _.toInt ).foreach( println )
```

Comment: Very useful answer. A small question, why scala won't treat `println(_.toInt)` a whole expression, and expand it to `(x) => println(x.toInt)`. What's the rule?

Comment: @Freewind As you can see, there is an ambiguity of whether to resolve `.foreach(println(_.toInt))` as `.foreach(x => println(x.toInt))` or as `.foreach(println(x => x.toInt))`. Since Scala compiler doesn't do much of reverse analysis, it just chooses the most simple resolution, which is the closest scope.

Comment: It's not a case of the compiler not doing enough analysis: the language spec is very clear, and you illustrate the kind of ambiguity that *would* arise if the spec were changed to make Freewind's example do what he thought it would!

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Probably you didn't get me right. I didn't say anything about the spec, I just explained how the compiler makes its decision. Concerning the "clearness" of the spec, I would argue that. Freewind's expectations for `.foreach( println(_.toInt) )` are quite justified by how `.foreach( println(_) )` gets interpreted. To me this incoherent behaviour is an example of some bad design decisions adding unnecessary complexity to the language.