# Is it possible to create a partially applied function with named parameter?

Tags: scala

This function is provided

```
def foo( a: String = "bar", b: Int = 1, c: String = "default" ): String
```

Is there a way to create a partial function `String => String` without specifying `a` and `b`? My approach `foo( c = _: String )` does unfortunately not compile. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: By `a` dou you mean the string "a"??. i.e. you want to give the default value as the name of the variable?

Comment: By `a` I mean the parameter a, I'll modify the example bit to reduce the confusion (:

Comment: Just on a side note, you mean _partially applied function_. A _partial function_ is a function which is not defined for all inputs ([see the scala doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction))

Comment: And `(c: String) => foo(c = c)` isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: @TravisBrown That's how I'm currently doing it. I've been hoping I could throw in a little more syntactic sugar to get rid of the boilerplate code. Looks like I'm out of luck.

Comment: This answer is popular http://stackoverflow.com/a/5259946/1296806 I think because of the phrase "tightest non-degenerate scope" which sounds kind of kinky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by Travis this works:

```
def foo( a: String = "bar", b: Int = 1, c: String = "default" ): String = s"$a$b$c"                                                
val fooc = (c: String) => foo(c = c)            
fooc("myc")
//> res0: String = bar1myc
```

Comment: Accepted as it is a valid alternative to my approach although it is not the answer I've been hoping for.

Comment: This helped me figure something out, but I really do wish it was possible to do something like `model.copy(field:T = _)` and get back a `T => model`