# Scala lambda functions underscore syntax

Tags: scala

What is the reason the second function does nor compile:

```
case class Person(name: String)
def f1(op: Option[Person]) = op.map(p => Seq(p.name)) // GOOD
def f2(op: Option[Person]) = op.map(Seq(_.name))      // WRONG
```

P.S. I see comments pointing stackoverflow.com/a/7673633/6059889 as an answer to the question, but I do not understand how this answers it. According to rule 2, I'd expect `Seq(_.name)` to become `x => Seq(x.name)`, which should work.

P.P.S. Thanks, Dima, for the link to: [Underscore in Named Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259006/underscore-in-named-arguments): **link to _ always picks the tightest non-degenerate scope it can**, I get it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7673633/6059889 this answer contains the different interpretations of the _ syntax in lambda functions. I think in the second case it will interpret the Seq as an anonymous function and can't infer its return type.

Comment: Yes, these should be merged

Comment: Please, explain how the links answers this question. In the second case you mention `Seq(_.name))` becomes `x => Seq(x.name)`, which is exactly what is needed. How does that explain why it is wrong?

Comment: @AssenKolov It actually becomes `Seq(x => x.name)`. 
A better explanation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259006/underscore-in-named-arguments