# Why do I have to cast elements of RDD[Int] when sorting?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Why is it that I have to cast elements of `RDD[Int]` to `Int` or `String` to use it with sortBy (Spark 1.6)?

For e.g. this gives me an error

```
val t = sc.parallelize(1 to 9) //t: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]
t.sortBy(_, ascending=false) //error: missing parameter type ...
```

whereas this works

```
t.sortBy(_.toInt, ascending=false).collect //Array[Int] = Array(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

t.sortBy(_.toString,ascending=false).collect //Array[Int] = Array(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

And why is it casting to `toString` above returns `Array[Int]` instead of `Array[String]` or `Array[Char]` ?

Just started learning spark, so please go easy on me :-).

Comment: You're collecting an `RDD[Int]` in both cases, so that's the return type. Regarding the sorting, the `_` is untyped, so it doesn't know how to sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of scope, as described here [Underscore in Named Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5259006) and hinted by the error message:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function 
  ((x$1) => t.sortBy(x$1, ascending = false))
```

You can use `identity` instead:

```
t.sortBy(identity, ascending=false)
```

> And why is it casting to toString above returns Array[Int] instead of Array[String] or Array[Char] ?

Because `_.toString` is used only for comparing, not to transform the data.