# Why underline not work in some scenario of monad?

Tags: scala

Underline `_` cannot work for some scenario in following code:

```
case class Item
(
  para: Int
)

val a = List(1, 2)
val b = List(Item(1), Item(2))

a foreach {
  perA => println(perA * 2) // Line A: ok
}

a foreach {
  println(_) // Line B: ok
}

a foreach {
  println(_ * 2) // Line C: not ok
}

b foreach {
  perB => println(perB.para) // line D: ok
}

b foreach {
  println(_.para) // line E: not ok
}
```

Could someone explain for me about line C & line E, thanks.

Comment: Here is a complementary question: [usage of underscore in lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673545/usage-of-in-scala-lambda-functions/7673633#7673633). There, the OP wondered why `a.groupBy(_)` is not expanded into `a.groupBy(x => x)`. In your case, `x` was inserted "too deep inside", in the linked question, the `x` was inserted "too far outside".

Comment: Here is [another very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259006/underscore-in-named-arguments), but instead of a `_.member`, a named parameter assignment `paramName = _` got in the way. It contains a very consise rule (quote Seth Tisue): "_ always picks the tightest non-degenerate scope it can" *(I'm trying to understand how this is a duplicate. It feels like it should be, but I can't find an exact match.  )*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** the argument of the lambda can be inserted at an unexpected position. Instead of taking

```
a foreach { println(_.blah) }
```

and building

```
a foreach { x => println(x.blah) }
```

out of it, the compiler instead builds

```
a foreach { println( x => x.blah ) }
```

and then fails to derive the type for the argument `x`.

---

**A)** This is the most explicit way to write down the lambda, the only way to make it clearer would be to add a type:

```
a foreach { perA => println(perA * 2) }
```

is the same as

```
a foreach { (x: Int) => println(x * 2) }
```

This should obviously work.

**B)** This works because it's one way to write down the function automatically generated from `println`. It is equivalent to any of the six variants below:

```
a foreach { (x: Int) => println(x) }
a foreach { x => println(x) }
a foreach { println(_) }
a foreach { println _ }
a foreach { println }
a foreach println
```

**C)** Because of the `* 2`, this here

```
a foreach { println(_ * 2) }
```

can no longer be considered just `println(_)`. Instead, it is interpreted as

```
a foreach { println( { (x: ??!) => x * 2 } ) }
```

and since `println` takes no function-valued arguments, it cannot determine what the type of `x` is supposed to be, and exits with an error.

**D)** Is essentially the same as **A**, it works, I hope it's clear.

**E)** Is a variation of **C**, but this time, the type-checker isn't looking for something with method `*(i: Int)`, but instead it's looking for something with a member `para`.

This here:

```
b foreach { println(_.para) }
```

is again interpreted as a `foreach` with a function which ignores elements of `b` and returns the constant value of the expression `println(_.para)`,
that is:

```
b foreach { println( { (x: ??!) => x.para } ) }
```

Again, the inner expression `println( { (x: ??!) => x.para } )` does not make any sense, because `println` does not expect function-valued arguments (it can handle `Any`, but it's not enough to derive the type of `x`).